# What is the meaning of 江山入画

Tags: translation, meaning

Please, can you explain me the exact meaning of 江山入画? It is a name of a novel. However I am not sure of exact meanging. I know that 江山 means country, 画 is painting. Please what it mean all together ?

Comment: Can you provide more context?

Answer (score 2):

入 means to enter, 江山入画 literally means 'the country enters the painting'.

The title 江山入画 (The country in paintings) is very straight forward. you can also interpret 江山 literally  as 'rivers and mountains', and 江山入画 can describe 'rivers and mountains in paintings'  if 山水畫 (landscape painting) is what the main character does

There is an idiom '江山如画',  it means the country is as beautiful as a painting (so beautiful it seems unreal)

Answer (score 0):

Please also note 入 is a homophone of 如 with different tones. And 江山如画 is a 成语 originated from [念奴娇·赤壁怀古](https://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%BF%B5%E5%A5%B4%E5%A8%87%C2%B7%E8%B5%A4%E5%A3%81%E6%80%80%E5%8F%A4), a well known poetry from the poet [苏轼](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Su_Shi)

> 江山如画，一时多少豪杰。